# Refactoring a flask-restful api endpoint into separate linked resources

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm re-factoring some code on an API and I'm unsure how to structure the related Models in Flask-Restful and SQLAlchemy. Partial solution half-way down the page.

What I'm essentially attempting to do is the the equivalent of this SQL

```
SELECT tags.name
FROM events, tags, events_tags 
WHERE events.id = events_tags.event_id 
  AND tags.id = events_tags.tag_id
  AND events.id = 1
```

My routes originally had an event with a nested set of tags and the JSON returned by `api.add_resource(Events, '/events/<int:event_id>')` was structured something like this:

```
{  
    "event_id":"1",
    "title":"Sample title",
    "tags":[
            {"name":"earthquake"},
            {"name":"infrastructure"}
           ]
}
```

It's the `tags` which I want to separate out into a separate endpoint:

So that we end up with two JSON outputs

`api.add_resource(Event, '/events/<int:event_id>')`

```
[
    {  
        "event_id":"1",
        "title":"Sample title",
    }
]
```

`api.add_resource(Tags, '/events/<int:event_id>/tags')`

```
[
    {"name":"earthquake"},
    {"name":"infrastructure"}
]
```

As I'm working through the problem, and being aware that any given tag might belong to multiple events I'm thinking that the solution would need the following done:

1. An event / tag joining table in the DB.
2. A function for a `tag_association_table` in the api
3. A `TagsListModel` (but I'm unsure as to whether this references this `tag_association_table` or not.

Any help is welcome.

### TAG MODEL

```
class TagsListModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    events = db.relationship("EventModel", secondary=tag_association_table, backref="tag")
```

### TAG SERIALISER

```
class TagSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = TagModel
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = True

    id = auto_field(load_only=True)
```

### TAG LOADER

```
class Tags(Resource):
    # GET
    def get(self, event_id):
        schema = TagsListSchema()
        result = db.session.query(TagsListModel).filter(TagsListModel.event_id == event_id)
        return schema.dump(result, many=True), 200

    # POST
    def post(self, event_id):
        event_id = event_id
        name = request.json['name']

        tag = TagsListModel(name=name)


        db.session.add(tag)
        db.session.commit()

        data = ({'id' :tag.id,
                    'name': tag.name
                })

        #print(data)

        response = jsonify(data)
        response.status_code = 200 # or 400 or whatever
        return response
```

### ROUTES

```
# Route_1
## GET (RETURNS) A LIST OF EVENTS
## POST (CREATES) AN EVENT
api.add_resource(Events, '/events')

# Route_2
## GET (RETURNS) A SINGLE EVENT
# PUTS (UPDATES) A SINGLE EVENT
api.add_resource(Events, '/events/<int:event_id>')

# Route_3
## GET (RETURNS) ALL TAGS FOR AN EVENT
api.add_resource(Tags, '/events/<int:event_id>/tags')
```

---

### Partial Solution

I have been able to retrieve the values on a *joining table*. These are correctly filtered and provides the following output:

```
[
    {
        "tag_id": 1, 
        "event_id": 1
    }, 
    {
        "tag_id": 2,
        "event_id": 1
    }
]
```

#### Endpoint

I call the below endpoint with the `int:event_id` value of `1`:

```
# Route_3
## GET (RETURNS) ALL TAGS FOR AN EVENT
api.add_resource(EventTags, '/events/<int:event_id>/tags')
```

#### Loader

```
class EventTags(Resource):
    # GET
    def get(self, event_id):
        schema = TagSchema()
        result = db.session.query(TagModel).filter(TagModel.event_id == event_id)
        return schema.dump(result, many=True), 200

    # POST
    def post(self, event_id):
        event_id = event_id
        tag_id = request.json['id']

        tag = TagsListModel(id=id)


        db.session.add(tag)
        db.session.commit()

        data = ({'id' :tag.id
                })

        #print(data)

        response = jsonify(data)
        response.status_code = 200 # or 400 or whatever
        return response
```

#### Schema

```
class TagSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = TagModel
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = True

    tag_id = auto_field(load_only=False)
    event_id = auto_field(load_only=False)
```

#### Model

```
class TagModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "events_tags"

    tag_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

I had to:

1. Create a model for each table where it didn't exist: (EventTag, Tag)
2. Modify my tag schema to match the values I wanted to hide from the `Tag` table
3. Modify my EventTags Loader to filter on the columns across the three tables

### MODELS

```
class TagModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(db.String, nullable=False)


class EventTagModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "events_tags"

    tag_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

### SCHEMA

```
class TagSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = TagModel
        load_instance = True
        include_fk = True

    id = auto_field(load_only=True)  # Only one field removed so this remained pretty identical.
```

### LOADER

```
result = db.session.query(TagModel)
    .filter(TagModel.id == EventTagModel.tag_id)
    .filter(EventModel.id == EventTagModel.event_id)
    .filter(EventTagModel.event_id == event_id)

#   result = db.session.query(TagModel).         # REMOVED
#       filter(TagModel.event_id == event_id).   # REMOVED
```